# Why I m getting empty report using a json file as datasource?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I m using tibco jaspersoft studio to generate a report

droping fields in the detail band is getting all data but when I try to use a table I m getting two empty pages.

the printing option is set to print all sections no details

here is my data json file

```
[ {
    "clientName" : "SEMMOUD Abderrazak",
    "clientPhone" : "043303854",
    "codeExterne" : "CLI201801",
    "email" : "talcorpdz@gmail.com",
    "clientType" : 0,
    "clientEtat" : 1,
    "identifiant" : "TalcorpDZ",
    "contacts" : [ {
        "nom" : "Taleb",
        "prenom" : "Mohammed Housseyn",
        "telephonePortable" : "04330256699",
        "email" : null
    } ],
    "adresses" : [ {
        "adress" : "Batiments des enseignants Mohammed Khemisti",
        "ville" : "Maghnia"
    } ]
}, {
    "clientName" : "",
    "clientPhone" : "",
    "codeExterne" : "sdsqdqs",
    "email" : "talcorpdz@gmail.com",
    "clientType" : 1,
    "clientEtat" : 1,
    "identifiant" : "sqdsqd",
    "contacts" : [ {
        "nom" : "Taleb",
        "prenom" : "Mohammed",
        "telephonePortable" : "+213778217469",
        "email" : null
    } ],
    "adresses" : [ {
        "adress" : "Batiments des enseignants ",
        "ville" : "Maghnia"
    } ]
} ]
```

and here is my report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="refClient" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="758785c8-ae8f-49bd-9995-19c9827a7ebb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="refcliJsonAdapter"/>
    <subDataset name="jsonRefClient" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="1dcb37f4-96e4-472a-aadb-309de9d05089">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="refcliJsonAdapter"/>
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="clientName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="clientName"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[clientName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="clientName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="clientName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[clientName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="258" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="40" y="10" width="660" height="200" uuid="a43c33cc-e3f9-470c-8df4-1c36301c869e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.proportional" value="true"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.next" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="jsonRefClient" uuid="b4a19c4b-0cb1-481a-a9ba-739ce437135a">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="660" uuid="eda57584-75da-466c-8182-d466356f3cc4">
                        <jr:tableHeader height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="660" height="30" uuid="d349739f-3e3d-4012-8e52-3b5c7bd75eb9"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[clientName]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="660" height="30" uuid="fb6bb53f-e520-48f4-81e0-189ae5058656"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{clientName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Alex K, you have not properly edited the report JRXML and it is now in an uncompilable state.

Comment: It is a problem, indeed, with huge templates and unnecessary code. Most people don't even bother reading the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I find it hard, sometimes, to cleanup a report from within JSS, so I do it manually instead. And I don't think that's easy for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table dataSet is not actually linked to any data, at runtime. A quick fix is to:

1. Export your JSON Data Adapter to a file on the same level as your report, let's say **refcliJsonAdapter.xml**
2. Add the `net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter` property to your table dataSet, something like:

   ```
   <subDataset name="jsonRefClient" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="1dcb37f4-96e4-472a-aadb-309de9d05089">
       ...
       <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="refcliJsonAdapter.xml"/>
       ...
   </subDataset>
   ```
3. Preview the report against the `One Empty Record` built-in Data Adapter if you don't want repeating tables.